# how to show dynamic viewmodel in angular

Tags: angular, angular14

In an Angular project
I want to create a component that can display any viewmodel.
I want to create a dynamic report that shows any viewmodel we give it
But I do not know how to do this

How to dynamically get property value from model by string name?

please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built-in Javascript Method `Object.entries` to dynamically retrieve the properties of the ViewModel and render them accordingly.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries